# Excel crashes and misdisplays files written using Apache POI (in the Excel 87-2003 .XLS format)

Tags: excel, export, string-formatting, apache-poi, autofilter

our Java EE applications writes large (>3000 rows, >300 columns) Excel files using Apache POI. We have implemented the customer's requirement that many (>500) of the cells in the written file have a partial text formatting, i.e. the text in *one* cell is partially red and bold, and partially black.

Apache POI does not complain when writing the files, and they can be opened, BUT Excel 97 misdisplays them: parts of the cells have the wrong font size, and cells with multiple font colors cannot be changed (altering the font size on them does not work).

Also, Excel 2010 complains that the file is insecure (when downloaded from the server), and both Excel 97 and Excel 2010 crash on the exported files frequently.

The previous version of the application used JExcelApi and did not write multiformatted text cells. The files generated by the server using the previos (JExcelApi-powered) version of the application do display normally in Office2010, without the security warning.

Did anyone come across these issues and if so, how can I fix them?

Also, did anyone figure out why setting AutoFilters fails to show up in Office 2010 in the specified, yet shows up in Excel 97 correctly (so it sometimes crashes or works just until one AutoFilter is selected?).

Finally, I have tried to roundtrip an Excel export of the older version of the application, and found that Apache POI reduces the file size by >35%, while breaking the file's contents - although no changes are applied (just reading the file into a HSSF Workbook and re-writing it into a ByteArrayOutputStream. Did anyone figure out how to prevent POI from altering the written file?

Thanks,

Michael

Comment: Are there textboxes or other objects in the file?

Comment: Excel 97 - 2003 has a limit of 256 columns.  If you're attempting to write a file with more columns than this that may be part of your problem.

Comment: @datatoo: There are neither textboxes nor images, comments or formulars.

Comment: @Jesse: The described issues occur even if we write less then 200 columns.

Comment: How many styles are you creating for your formatting? There is a limit in Excel on the number of styles, so you need to re-use them, rather than creating one per cell

Comment: Note: If the version of Office is currently supported and the crash shows up in a patched version, and WinDbg or similar shows the memory address that it tried to access being >=0x1000, please send the file to MSRC.

Comment: We are having similar problems even with smaller files. The users are not even able to navigate inside the files. Deleting a column takes  over 90 seconds in my i7 8gb ram 250gb ssd disk windows 7 pc  Looks like there is some sort of comaptibility issue between poi - office 2007 / 2010

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a lot of questions here, but it sounds like POI is outputting records that 97 is misinterpreting. There are significant differences between a 97' .xls and a 2003 .xls. The dialog behaving strangely is often a symptom of a malformed record. Excel 2010 has a binary file validator that it runs internally on any of the binary file format files (BIFF). It will pick up on any records that aren't to the BIFF specifications.

I'm not sure what's going on with the AutoFilters or the altering behavior.

If you're having a lot of trouble with POI, you may wish to check out [OfficeWriter](http://www.officewriter.com) which does a pretty good job with 2010 validation and styles in general.

DISCLAIMER: I'm one of the engineers who wrote the latest version.

Comment: Thanks Nick, maybe you can help me with one of the potential troublemakers: how do we properly write a linebreak into a cell of an Excel 97 file? "\n" from Java (standard line break) do show up correctly, but maybe it's still a hidden troublemaker?

Comment: Sorry, missed your question. Try \r\n. POI should be able to write out String records correctly - they're pretty much just Unicode. 97 and 2003 .xls aren't super picky, but the 2010 validator certainly is.

Answer (score 0):

The root cause of our problem was traced to conditional formatting introduced in the excel template files. This resulted in the output file having conditional formatting.
We got rid of the conditional formatting and all is well now ! 
The problem manifests very severely when the users try to access the files over network. 
Conditional formatting can be removed from excel. 
Do ensure to remove the conditional formatting from all sheets / styles  as well.